# svmono template and `\mathcal`

Tags: fonts, mathcal, sv-classes

Why, with Springer's  `svmono` template, do the letters written with the `\mathcal` font change? It seems that `\mathcal` becomes `\mathscr.`

**Edit:**
Look at this image:

[image]

With the `svmono` template `\mathcal` returns the first alphabet and not the (classical) latter.

Here the packages I use in my document:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[colorlinks={true},linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[frame,width=15truecm,height=23.5truecm,center]{crop}
```

With this settings I have the above strange behavior of `\mathcal`.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal (working) example? It would help solvers a lot. A note for solvers: `wget http://ftp.utia.cas.cz/pub/staff/studeny/monogr/svmono.cls`

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Please add more info to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `mathptmx` package draws its calligraphic letters from the RSFS font, which explains the behavior you get, which has nothing to do with the `svmono` class.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABCDEF}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to reinstate the Computer Modern calligraphic letters, add

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

to your preamble.