# \mathcal{L} looks too "curly"

Tags: amssymb

I'm using the `\mathcal{L}` to get a curly L (the upper "L" in the image below). However, I get the other "L" (the lower "L" in the image below). I do include `\usepackage{amssymb}` in my `.tex` file.

My template can be found [here](https://github.com/briandealwis/ubcdiss/blob/master/diss.tex)

[image]

Comment: See [Script fonts for mathematical use available to LaTeX users](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/math/scriptfonts.pdf), which suggests some use of `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`...

Comment: This is as a result of including [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx).

Comment: This provides the answer: [`svmono` template and `\mathcal`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170704/5764) That is, `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` to restore the old `\mathcal` usage.

Comment: @Werner, this worked great! If you post it, I can vote it.

Comment: We'll mark this as a duplicate since the solution would be similar. You question will remain as it has received at least one vote. Future visitors who find this question will be notified of the duplicate link. You can up-vote the linked answer.